# The texture does not load after you export to jar

Tags: java, opengl, jar

I have a problem with my problem with my game created with the help of lwjgl 2.9.3. When you export a project to a jar. The program does not want to read through some of the textures.
In eclipse everything worked properly. All files to be loaded are in a jar.

The error that appears

```
Exception in thread "Thread-42" java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found: Pajak/chodzenie/1.png
    at
```

org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(ResourceLoader.java:69)

The method that reads texture

```
 public static Texture LoadTexture(String path,String fileType){
    Texture tex = null;

    InputStream in = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(path);
    try {
        tex = TextureLoader.getTexture(fileType, in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tex;

}
```

Loading textures

[image]

Theoretically, everything is right, however, it does not work. With the rest of the files I have no problems. Thanks for the help

[image]

Comment: What is the file structure of your project and how do you load other files, also with ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream? Edit: Could you also post a list of the contents of the JAR? Both things might clear your problem up.

Comment: All files are loaded in the same way. Files with the spider is at the bottom